# Where is my mounted/shared folder located?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I am running Ubuntu via VirtualBox and have mounted a folder:

[image]

However, I can't seem to find it anywhere on my VM Ubuntu.

Is there a default location for mounted folders?

I have looked at the network folder and don't seem to be able to access it:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Check the network folders. The virtualbox shared folders usually appear as network shares.

Comment: I have tried that but no luck. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/161759/693277). And I think you need to install Guest Additions in the guest OS first.

Comment: @Ramhound: The screenshot doesn't show any illegal characters though?

Comment: @grawity For completeness I tried a folder with no dots present and still got the same result.

Comment: Install the guest additions and maybe Samba?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some steps - defining the share in VirtualBox could possibly
not be enough to make it appear inside the guest, or it may appear in unexpected
places and unexpected name.

There are a few very highly upvoted answers in the following posts:

- [How to mount a VirtualBox shared folder? [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/674974/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder)
  (closed as belonging to Super User, but never migrated ...)
- [How to access a shared folder in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox)

Unfortunately, the answers differ, although very highly upvoted, so seems to depend
on the Linux or VirtualBox versions. I will summarize them below.

**Pre-requisites**

You must install Guest Additions in the guest, then reboot it.

You might also be required to add your user to the group `vboxsf` by one of:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf your_username
sudo adduser your_username vboxsf
```

To check that the user is not already in the `vboxsf` group, use the `id` command.

**Manual mount**

Here one specifies the mount point of the share.
(Remember that there were users for whom this did not work.)

```
cd ~
mkdir myshare
sudo mount -t vboxsf DATA ~/myshare/
```

`vboxsf` stand for mount type of "VirtualBox shared folder".

If you are required to login as root for that, you might enter similarly :

```
mkdir /home/your_username/myshare
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 DATA /home/your_username/myshare
```

**Auto mount by VirtualBox**

VirtualBox may auto-mount the share, but not where expected.
It might be found in the folder `/media/sf_DATA` and may be accessible only by root,
which then requires root login for the following commands.

You can change where the folder is mounted by using the `VBoxControl` command,
which is a part of Guest Additions. May require reboot.
For example, to change the mount point from `/media/sf_...` to
`/home/your_username/sf_...`
use the following command to set the VirtualBox shared folder `guestproperty`:

```
sudo VBoxControl guestproperty set /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir /home/your_username/
```

To confirm the change, use `get`:

```
sudo VBoxControl guestproperty get /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir
```

You may alternatively create a link to the folder by :

```
ln -s /media/sf_DATA /home/your_username/DATA
```

**Conclusion**

The answers I found vary and you might need to try and find which are the
commands, or mix of the above commands, which will work for you.
In case of success, please let our readers know which commands you used.

Further reading :

- [Virtual Box User Manual - shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders)
- [Create a shared Folder between Host OS and Guest OS ( Virtual Box)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-shared-folder-host-os-guest-os-virtual-box/)
- [VirtualBox Guest properties](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-guestprops)